# Docker PHP Image when using Redis extension exited on signal 2 (SIGINT)

Tags: php, docker, redis, docker-compose

I have the following DockerFile and docker-compose.yml for an Laravel application. I have just added Redis today and this appeared in my terminal in the end of `docker-compose up` when I tried to connect and use Redis from PHP.

```
zinc_app          | [23-Dec-2019 11:31:27] ALERT: oops, unknown child (32) exited on signal 2 (SIGINT). Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
zinc_app          | [23-Dec-2019 11:31:27] ALERT: oops, unknown child (31) exited on signal 2 (SIGINT). Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
zinc_app          | [23-Dec-2019 11:32:09] ALERT: oops, unknown child (20) exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL). Please open a bug report (https://bugs.php.net).
```

I am pretty sure the error came from the PHP Redis extension, because it didn't have the problem before. Have anyone encountered this problem before? Have I configured anything wrong?

I have tested this on another computer, but it didn't exhibit the same behavior. I have tried `docker system prune -a` and build and up again, but my computer still has the same problem.

As for the code I have run. I have run this in artisan tinker.

```php
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('zinc_redis', 6379);
$redis->get('1'); // The Oops message originated from this line.
```

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3.6'
services:

  #PHP Service
  zinc_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: zinc/php
    container_name: zinc_app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: zinc_app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - /tmp:/tmp #For CS Fixer
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  zinc_webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: zinc_webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Postgres Service
  zinc_db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    container_name: zinc_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: zinc
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: postgres
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql
      - ./postgres/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - app-network

  zinc_redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    container_name: zinc_redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - redisdata:/data
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
  redisdata:
    driver: local
```

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Switch to root user
USER root

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

RUN chown www:www /var/www

# Copy composer
COPY --chown=www:www composer.json composer.lock /var/www/

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    libzip-dev \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pgsql pdo_pgsql zip exif pcntl

# Enable igbinary & PHP Redis ext using igbinary
RUN pecl install -o -f igbinary && y | pecl install -o -f redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis igbinary

RUN rm -rf /tmp/pear

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www/

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Install packages
RUN composer global require hirak/prestissimo && composer install

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce the issue (used your docker-compose/Dockerfile, created empty laravel app and executed the 3 lines redis code in the default route) - have you maybe changed some redis related laravel conf too?

Comment: @Evil_skunk I tried executing the PHP code in tinker. I originally tried with the laravel redis facade and resulted in the problem, so I tried to execute vanilla PHP redis code. My redis commands work, it's just that the sigkill sigint messages keep flushing to my log. I have not changed the default laravel redis config, but have just disabled redis authentication in the conf file. Maybe I'll try rebuild my app completely and see if I have anything new.